# Perform a function on all couples of elements of my RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I will try to ask the problem in the general way.

I have a function like this

```
 myFunction (Object first, Object second)
```

And i have an rdd of Object `RDD [Object]`.

I need to perform myFunction on all rdd's elements, in the end of process I have to be sure that all the couples of my object are performed with the myfunction (.., ..)

One way, maybe, is create a broadcast variable (as a copy of my RDD), and than

```
 val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(rdd.collect())
 rdd_line.mapPartitions(p=> {
   var brd = broadcastVar.value
   var result = new ListBuffer[Double]()
   brd.foreach(b => {
     p.foreach(e => result+= myfunction(b ,e))
   })
   result.toList.toIterator
 })
```

There is another way to do this with better performance?

Comment: Calling collect on an entire big data object for the purpose to modify/broadcast it again is generally an anti-pattern.  Instead use Spark map, reduce, filter or something similar to transform the big data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RDD's `.cartesian` method to get an RDD containing all pairs of elements from the two. In this case, you want the RDD's cartesian with itself:

```
rdd.cartesian(rdd).map({ case (x, y) => myFunction(x, y) })
```

Note that this will include pairs of an element with itself, and pairs in both orders, i.e. (a, b) as well as (b, a). And (a, a).